# Convert string definition to javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the best way to convert a string return by an API to a javascript object. This is a result from ModelState validation in aspnet core.

the string would look like this {"cars[2].color", "blue"}

I need to convert "cars[2].color" to an object

```
 {
   cars: [
      {},
      {},
      {
      color: "blue"
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: If it's returning json, can't you simply access it via `data.cars[2].color`? Assuming `data` is the name of your function parameter (`function (data)`).

Comment: do you need to convert a path to an object? or a json string to an object? converting a path has quite a few assumptions...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the framework you are using to fetch the API, generally speaking it should be smart enough to do it for you automatically, particular if the API in aspnet is setting the content type as application/json in the response. For example, if using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/api/v1/cars',
    type:'get',
    dataType: 'json', //Optional, generally speaking
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data); // This will be an object
    }
});
```

In general if you want to convert some json text into an object in javascript you can use the native JSON.parse method:

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse("{
  cars: [
      {},
      {},
      {color: "blue"}
    ]
  }"); //Returns an object
```

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to parse the selector path, you can convert the segments into an array:

```js
function parsePath(string) {
 var rePropName = /[^.[\]]+|\[(?:(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(["'])((?:(?!\2)[^\\]|\\.)*?)\2)\]|(?=(?:\.|\[\])(?:\.|\[\]|$))/g
 
 var result = []
 string.replace(rePropName, function(match, number, quote, string) {
  result.push(quote ? string.replace(/\\(\\)?/g, '$1') : (number || match));
 });
 
 return result;
}
```

determining if each segment is meant to be an array vs an object cannot be certain though

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jsonStr = '{"cars":[{},{},{"color":"blue"}]}';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

console.log(jsonObj.cars[2]); // Object {color: "blue"}
```